# What does a triangle with a slashed zero in it represent?

Tags: symbol

In the block diagram for an RF component, there is a triangle with a slashed zero in it as below:

[image]

What is it meant to represent?

Comment: any context to it?

Comment: What component?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's an RF component but the documentation is confidential and requires an NDA!  I wish it was online, really annoying but unfortunately that's all I can show, (think transmitter/ mixers.)  I know I've seen it before...

Comment: Well, I would say it is some kind of differential opamp/buffer. Dunno about the zero (phi?) symbol.

Comment: maybe a differential amplifier with 0 dB gain. Used for directional isolation, perhaps.

Comment: It could be a phase shifter. It does look like a phi.

Comment: Well, you could provide at least *some* context. Like what kind of input it is getting and what kind of out put it is giving

Comment: @EugeneSh. high frequency >70GHz signal going to another triangle that seems to be a phase splitter 0/ 180 outputs and then to an antenna.  Unfortunately can't say more and there is literally no key for the block diagram.

Comment: @EugeneSh. https://github.com/benishor/rf-symbols perhaps an all pass?

Comment: You are not able to ask the NDA counterparty? They must have someone who can speak to the diagram.

Comment: @mkeith the NDA counterparty has become very unhelpful, I think they're more used to specialist engineers looking for tweaks rather than a customer trying to understand the tech.  My guess is an all pass differential amplifier but it would be nicer to have a reference to back up a guess.